# Event Listener in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently building a small alarm application with Vue.js. I want to have an eventListener on buttons with a class of "del" that calls a method and hands over the event, I'm using Vue's "mounted" feature for that:

```
mounted: function timeInterval () {
    var app = this;

    var del = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
    del.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      app.deleteAlarm(e);
    },
}
```

In that method I want to get the id of the button that was clicked and do something with it:

```
deleteAlarm: function (e) {
  var app = this;
  var id = e.target.id;
  app.alarms.splice(id, 1);
}
```

I spent hours on figuring out what's going wrong but I can't get it.

**Edit:** The way I want to do this is important, because the buttons are part of a dynamic list, that gets rendered via v-html. This is the method that adds the HTML to the data variable:

```
getAlarmList: function () {
  var app = this;
  app.alarmTable = '';
  for (let i=0; i<app.alarms.length; i++) {
    app.alarmTable += "<tr><td>"+app.alarms[i][0]+"</td><td>"+app.alarms[i][1]+":"+app.alarms[i][2]+":"+app.alarms[i][3]+"</td><td><button type=\"button\" id=\""+i+"\" class=\"btn btn-dark btn-sm del\">Löschen</button></td></tr>";
  }
```

And this is how the variable gets rendered out with the v-html directive:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-html="alarmTable">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry but i completely don't understnad. maybe try to explain what u want to do, instead of what u tried.  u want that on button click, to call a method that will delete an item for the array `alarms` ?

Comment: Correct, the diffculty is that I am rendering the buttons with a v-html directive that just renders a variable that contains the HTML as a string. Directives in that HTML string just get rendered out.

Comment: why u render button with v-html? why not normally inside a vue template?

Comment: Because it is a dynamic list, when you add an alarm each alarm has it's own button that should delete it.

Comment: can you please post more of your html ? i'm sure there is a much better way to do what u are doing. :)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to go about the event listener approach, but I think using the v-for directive with a vue template would allow you to do what you need.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-html="alarmTable">
    <template v-for="(alarm, index) in alarms">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ alarm[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ alarm[1] }}:{{ alarm[2] }}:{{ alarm[3] }}</td>
        <td>
          <button
            type="button"
            v-on:click="deleteAlarm(index)"
            class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
          >
            Löschen
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you could workshop your `deleteAlarm()` function to either delete the row, or delete the item from the `alarms` array.

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates an event listener and a binding.

```
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="del" id="1" class="deletable">Foo</button>
<button v-on:click="del" id="2" class="deletable">Bar</button>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted () {
      this.$el.querySelectorAll('.deletable').forEach( (button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log("delete from event handler:" + e.target.id);  
      })
      } );
    },
    methods: {
        del (e) {
        console.log("delete from a method:" + e.target.id);
      }
    }
})
```

**Update**: 
I updated the fiddle to demo both, the binding and an even listener.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8m37hrag/5/)

Comment: No, I am "rendering" the buttons by adding the HTML as a string to a data variable and displaing that variable via v-html, directives in that string just get rendered out.